# Duplicate symbol errors when compiling, first time seeing this

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am getting duplicate symbol errors when trying to compile. Error message is:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_SideBarCell._profilePic in:
    /Users/kex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-aoizqcetllkwnxgbqvmjyrxmxrbw/Build/Intermediates/myProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SideBarCell.o
    /Users/kex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-aoizqcetllkwnxgbqvmjyrxmxrbw/Build/Intermediates/myProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TabViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SideBarCell in:
    /Users/kex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-aoizqcetllkwnxgbqvmjyrxmxrbw/Build/Intermediates/myProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SideBarCell.o
    /Users/kex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-aoizqcetllkwnxgbqvmjyrxmxrbw/Build/Intermediates/myProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TabViewController.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SideBarCell in:
    /Users/kex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-aoizqcetllkwnxgbqvmjyrxmxrbw/Build/Intermediates/myProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SideBarCell.o
    /Users/kex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-aoizqcetllkwnxgbqvmjyrxmxrbw/Build/Intermediates/myProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TabViewController.o
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am not familiar with this type of error at all. Have the references in my project gotten confused? Would really appreciate some advice on this!!!

Comment: I had this issue on the latest Xcode 4. Cause: I included file.m instead of file.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Potential Cause-I:**

More likely, you have more than one with one of your (`.m` or `.h`) files are same name in your project.

**Potential Cause-II:**

You may include `file.m` instead of `file.h`

Comment: it was number 2!!! thank you! feel so stupid. It's the first time this has happened so wasn't looking for it. Will know what to look for in the future now. Thanks!